# Ruby gems in spring framework beans written in jruby

Tags: java, ruby, spring, rubygems, jruby

i'm new to the java world. I'm trying to use nokogiri gem inside the spring framework bean.

I follow this doc to include jruby script http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/dynamic-language.html.

And this proxy repo for maven
http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases

Everything works fine until i try to include nokogiri gem into the rb file.

This is my context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">

    <lang:jruby id="fetchingWorkerImpl"
                script-interfaces="com.xxx.lib.fetcher.commons.FetchingWorker"
                script-source="classpath:com/xxx/fetcher/rubydemo/fetching_worker_impl.rb"/>
</beans>
```

This is the ruby file fetching_worker_impl.rb

```
require 'java'
require 'rubygems'
require "bundler"
require 'nokogiri'
require "net/http"
require "uri"
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.commons.FetchingWorker
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.rubydemo.Response
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.rubydemo.Request
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.BaseResponse

class FetchingWorkerImpl

  def getRequestClass
    Request.java_class
  end

  def processRequest(request)
    log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger FetchingWorkerImpl.class.to_s
    begin

      log.info $:

      html = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.google.com/search?q=jruby'))
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

      texts = doc.css('h3 a.l').map { |i| i.text }

      request['links'] = texts.join "\n"

      return Response.new(request, 200, "Hello World From Ruby!")

    rescue Exception => e
      log.info("Request not handled: " + e.message)
      BaseResponse.new(request, 500, e.message)
    end
  end

end
```

And pom.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


<modelVersion>4.0.0
</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.fetcher</groupId>
<artifactId>fetcher-rubydemo</artifactId>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>fetcher-rubydemo</name>

<properties>
    <lib.fetcher.interface.version>1.0.2</lib.fetcher.interface.version>
    <lib.fetcher.commons.version>1.0.0</lib.fetcher.commons.version>
    <lib.commons.version>1.0.0</lib.commons.version>

    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>libreader@scm.xxx.com</id>
        <url>sftp://scm.xxx.com/home/maven/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>rubygems-proxy</id>
        <name>Rubygems Proxy</name>
        <url>http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>fetcher-rubydemo</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.xxx.fetcher.rubydemo.Start</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assemble/deploy.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.28.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.28.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JRUBY -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
        <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RUBY GEMS -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>rubygems</groupId>
        <artifactId>nokogiri</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <type>gem</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- xxx -->

    .....


    <!-- SPRING -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- LOGGING -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- APACHE -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
</project>
```

Every time i try to run the jar file i get this exception
`org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- nokogiri`

I see nokogiri gem in the libs directory however cannot include it in the rb file.

What is the right way to use gems inside spring framework beans written in jruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seem's like jruby cannot find nokigiri classpath. Try 'puts $:' to see what ruby load path actualy is. Although java classpath is counted. You could try running your app with adding nokogiri classpath using '-cp'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add FetchingWorkerImpl.new at the end of file.

```
require 'java'
require 'rubygems'
require "bundler"
require 'nokogiri'
require "net/http"
require "uri"
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.commons.FetchingWorker
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.rubydemo.Response
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.rubydemo.Request
java_import com.xxx.lib.fetcher.io.json.BaseResponse

class FetchingWorkerImpl

  def getRequestClass
    Request.java_class
  end

  def processRequest(request)
    log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger FetchingWorkerImpl.class.to_s
    begin

      log.info $:

      html = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.google.com/search?q=jruby'))
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

      texts = doc.css('h3 a.l').map { |i| i.text }

      request['links'] = texts.join "\n"

      return Response.new(request, 200, "Hello World From Ruby!")

    rescue Exception => e
      log.info("Request not handled: " + e.message)
      BaseResponse.new(request, 500, e.message)
    end
  end

end

FetchingWorkerImpl.new
```